# Flutter, how do i make my icon same size as my DropdownButtonFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this question is easy for you, especially for veterans, because I am new so I am still confusedHow do i make my Icon same size as my DropdownButtonFormField?

```
            Container(
                width: (globals.screenWidth * 0.85),
                height: (globals.screenHeight * 0.07),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.brown),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                ),
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                  iconSize: 20,
                  icon: Container(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: globals.fontsize_19,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  value: _selectedLocation,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedLocation = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: _locations.map((location) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: new Text(location),
                      value: location,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )
                ),
```

I tried this `iconSize: 50,` but this is the result

[image]

this is the result

[image]

this is what i want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero
      ),
```

to your DropdownButtonFormField and just add an Expanded widget as parent of your Icon widget.