# how fit icon height to doropdownbuttonfield height in flutter

Tags: flutter

i want fit height of icon but height dont change

i read this topic but no use
[Flutter, how do i make my icon same size as my DropdownButtonFormField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460327/flutter-how-do-i-make-my-icon-same-size-as-my-dropdownbuttonformfield)

it is my code

```
DropdownButtonFormField(

                     //iconSize: 20,
                     icon: Container(
                       height:30,
                       width:30,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(

                           color: Colors.red,

                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0))
                       ),

                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                         color: Colors.white,
                       ),
                     ),
                     
                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                         contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right:8.0),
                         enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                           borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.grey[100],style: BorderStyle.solid),
                           gapPadding: 0.0,
                           borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                             const Radius.circular(10.0),
                           ),
                         ),
                         filled: true,

                         labelText: "numbers",
                        
                     isExpanded: true,
                     onChanged: (String Value) {
                       setState(() {
                         dropdownValue = Value;

                       });
                     },
                     items: numlist
                         .map((cityTitle) => DropdownMenuItem(
                         value: cityTitle, child: Text("$cityTitle")))
                         .toList(),
                   )
```

result is same this image ,please guide me.

[image]

Comment: have you tried  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero

Comment: yes i tried but no use. i think this widget has top and buttom padding any way